# How do you make a counter using a text file in C?

Tags: c

I'm new at programming and I'm having a hard time making a permanent counter so that every time I terminate a program the program will still remember the count. I tried using files however I'm not quite sure whats happening

```
 printf("Entera number:\t");
 scanf("%d", &Num);

 sprintf(FILENAME, "counter.%d.txt", Num);
 FILE *counter;

 int Count, NewCount;

 counter = fopen(FILENAME, "w+");
 if (NULL != counter) {
 fseek(counter, 0, SEEK_END);
 int size = ftell(counter);

 if (0 == size) {
 fprintf(counter, "1");
 } 

 else if (size > 0) {

  rewind(counter);
  fscanf(counter, "%d", &Count);
  NewCount = Count + 1;
  fprintf(counter, "%d", NewCount);

}
fclose(counter);
```

I wanna check if theres already a file created and it has a number stored inside it. if there is no file or there is no info inside the file I want it to store 1. If i open the file again, it will get the number in the file and add 1 to it and replace the 1 with 2 and so on.

Comment: you are not storing the number in the file, you are usong the number as part of the file name. You need to open one file and wrtie to it with fprintf

Comment: @pm100 OP is doing both: using a user-specified number in the filename, **and** reading/writing a value in the file.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], that is, something we can copy, paste and compile.

Comment: Why not simply open your file, read `Count`, close the file, open a new temporary file in `"w"` mode, write `NewCount` to the temporary file, close it. After validating the close, remove your old file and rename your temporary file to old file name? That allows full validation of the process all the way through and you are not at risk of losing your count if something goes wrong up to the point you remove and rename. There is no need to seek anywhere, you are always writing a single value to the new file which replaces the old one.

Answer (score 3):

The following program:

1. Checks if the file exists and has a number stored inside it.
2. If yes, increments the number stored.
3. Otherwise, ensures that the file exists and contains `1` by the time it finishes execution.
4. **Is a modified version of the program provided in the question** so that it is easier for the person asking the question to understand. As the comments point out, there are ways to improve the program. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72671355/8659747) for something better.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Count = 0;

    char FILENAME[] = "Counter.txt";
    FILE *counter = fopen(FILENAME, "a+");
    if (NULL != counter)
    {
        fseek(counter, 0, SEEK_END);
        int size = ftell(counter);

        if (size == 0)
        {
            printf("Number not found. Writing 1.\n");
            fprintf(counter, "1");
        }

        else if (size > 0)
        {
            rewind(counter);
            fscanf(counter, "%d", &Count);
            int NewCount = Count + 1;
            fclose(counter);
            counter = fopen(FILENAME, "w");
            fprintf(counter, "%d", NewCount);
            printf("Incremented the existing number!\n");
        }
    
        fclose(counter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to [ISO C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C), the return value of `ftell` is not necessarily the size of the file. From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell) of `ftell`: "If the stream is open in text mode, the value returned by this function is unspecified and is only meaningful as the input to fseek()." Your code may work on most [platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform), but it is not guaranteed to work on all ISO C compliant platforms.

Comment: I think this is preferable to using a binary file. I would also output a "\n", don't use `ftell`, and check the return value of `fscanf`.

Comment: I put a note in there linking to Andreas' answer.

Answer (score 1):

One problem in your program is that opening the file in `"w+"` mode will destroy all the file contents, if the file already exists. This behavior is desired after reading the counter, but not before reading the counter. Therefore, you should first open the file in `"r"` mode, read the counter,  and then close and reopen it in `"w"` mode, destroying the previous file contents.

The following program will attempt to open a file named `counter.txt` and attempt to read the counter. If opening the file or reading the counter fails, then the counter will be set to `1`. Otherwise, the counter will be incremented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILENAME "counter.txt"

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp;
    int counter;

    //attempt to open file and read counter
    fp = fopen( FILENAME, "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        counter = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //read counter and increment it, on failure set it to 1
        if ( fscanf( fp, "%d", &counter ) != 1 )
        {
            counter = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            counter += 1;
        }

        //cleanup
        fclose( fp );
    }

    //attempt to open file for output, overwriting all
    //file contents
    fp = fopen( FILENAME, "w" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //write updated counter to file
    fprintf( fp, "%d\n", counter );

    //cleanup
    fclose( fp );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this scenario you can use fscanf and fprintf combination which is nice couple :)

```
int main()
{
    static int globalCounter = 0;
    const char* FILENAME = "globalCounter.cfg";
    // Opening file in READ Mode!
    FILE *fd = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if (NULL == fd) {
        printf("We cannot read/found the File!");
        return 0;
    }
    // Read counter from the file!
    (void)fscanf(fd, "%d", globalCounter);
    // Close the file!
    (void)flose(fd);

    // Do some operations on your conter!
    // Like increasing by one!
    globalCounter++;
     
    // Opening file in WRITE Mode!
    FILE *fd = fopen(FILENAME, "w");
    if (NULL == fd) {
        printf("We cannot write/found the File!");
        return 0;
    }
    // Write counter to the file!
    (void)fprintf(fd, "%d", globalCounter);
    // Close the file!
    (void)flose(fd);
}
```

Comment: According to the question, if the file does not already exist, then a file should be created with a counter value of `1`. Your solution does not fulfill this requirement.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have added this for just example and show the roadmap for  Huwee!